# Why is my JavaScript "for of" loop not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I need a JS script to change the input of an HTML input element when you leave the input field in the way that all upper case characters are changed to lower case and vice versa.
When I write it using a normal for loop, it works, but when I use a for of loop, it's not working. Why?

```js
function changeCase() {
  const element = document.getElementById("string");
  const array = element.value.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (array[i].toLowerCase() == array[i]) ? array[i].toUpperCase() : array[i].toLowerCase();
  }
  element.value = array.join("");
}
```

```html
Enter a string: <input type="text" id="string" onchange="changeCase()">
```

```js
function changeCase() {
  const element = document.getElementById("string");
  const array = element.value.split("");
  for (let char of array) {
    char = (char.toLowerCase() == char) ? char.toUpperCase() : char.toLowerCase();
  }
  element.value = array.join("");
}
```

```html
Enter a string: <input type="text" id="string" onchange="changeCase()">
```

Comment: Assigning to `char` is just that. It doesn't modify some array. `char` is not an alias, it is a variable with its own memory.

Comment: You're simply returning the original array ``array``!

Comment: I've looked through the documentation at mdn web docs.

link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

On there it says:
> **Note:** Each iteration creates a new variable. Reassigning the variable inside the loop body does not affect the original value in the iterable.